# AttributeError: can't set attribute in splitting MNIST dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I'm work with pytorch `torchvision.datasets.MNIST`

to load the dataset I use:

```
mnist_data = datasets.MNIST('../data', train=True, download=True,
                    transform=transforms.Compose(
                    [transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))]))
```

and to split the data into training dataset I use:

```
mnist_data.train_data = (mnist_data.train_data.type(torch.FloatTensor)/255).bernoulli()
```

I got error: `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

How to solve this error?

Comment: Are you sure that the attribute "train_data" exists in object mnist_data?

Comment: Yes, there are `train_labels` attribute and `test_labels` as well. It seems the problem is solved when I used `data` and `targets` attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `torchvision.dataset.MNIST` you can change `train=True/False` for your train or test set.

From [docs](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/mnist.html#MNIST), MNIST class has `@property` train_data, so you can't set train_data as an attribute. You can change it to `mnist_data.data_train = ...`.